# Intuition behind Kernelized perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I understand the derivation of the kernelized perceptron function, but I'm trying to figure out the intuition behind the final formula

```
f(X) = sum_i (alpha_i*y_i*K(X,x_i))
```

Where `(x_i,y_i)` are all the samples in the training data, `alpha_i` is the number of times we've made a mistake on that sample, and `X` is the sample we're trying to predict (during training or otherwise). Now, I understand why the kernel function is considered to be a measure of similarity (since it's a dot product in a higher dimensional space), but what I don't get is how this formula comes together.

My original attempt was that we're trying to predict a sample based on how similar it is to the other samples - and multiply it by `y_i` so that it contributes the correct sign (points that are closer are better indicators of the label than points that are farther). But why should a sample that we've made several mistakes on contribute more?

**tl;dr: In a Kernelized perceptron, why should a sample that we've made several mistakes on contribute more to the prediction than ones we haven't made mistakes on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My original attempt was that we're trying to predict a sample based on how similar it is to the other samples - and multiply it by y_i so that it contributes the correct sign (points that are closer are better indicators of the label than points that are farther).

This is pretty much what's going on. Although the idea is if `alpha_i*y_i*K(X,x_i)` already is well classified, then you don't need to update it further.

But if the point is misclassified we need to update it. The best way would be in the opposite direction right? that's if the result is negative we should be adding a possitive quantity (y_i). If the result is possitive (and it is missclassified) then we want to sum a negative value (y_i again).

As you can see, y_i already give us the right update direction and hence we use a misclassification counter to give a magnitude to that update.

Comment: My confusion was mainly with the `alpha_i` aspect. You aren't looking at the number of mistakes made at the current sample `X`, you're looking at the number of mistakes in every other one. Considering that there's no explicit "update" occurring here, I'm wondering why a point that was misclassified multiple times contributes more to the final prediction (since the signum of that summation gives is the class) than one that's been correctly classified.

Comment: `I'm wondering why a point that was misclassified multiple times contributes more to the final prediction` Because it is the one interfering more, the ones that are already on set you don't want to touch them too much. Here a crazy analogy, a teacher and her `X_i` kids, where `alpha_i` is the time spent on each one. The teacher is more likely to spent more time with kids that are not doing properly.  Also remember that this is only meaningful for higher values of `K(X,x_i)` which corresponds to points that are similar, makes sense to focus on those points more than the rest.

Comment: Ahh OK, that makes sense! Thanks!